# Каждый первый

Tags: грамотная-речь

Только что в новостях: "**каждый первый** на приеме у кардиолога жалуется на нарушение ритма".   Я бы сказала **все** или просто **каждый**. В то же время сочетание  **каждый второй** - правильно. Верно ли сочетание **каждый первы**й?

Comment: Детский анекдот.  
- Это ты съел вишни? Все до одной?  
- Все до нуля!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, это просто тавтология. Тут слово "первый" можно легко отбросить, и фраза станет более удобоваримой: "Каждый на приеме у кардиолога...". И так будет понятно, что речь обо всех пациентах.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это выражение используется для усиления экспрессивности, т.к. аналогично привычным вариантам "каждый десятый, каждый третий" и т.д. И уж если **каждый первый** - это очень часто.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен, это может быть эмфатической (усилительной) конструкцией или, вернее сказать, иронией. Но чтобы утвекрждать наверняка, надо слышать текст.

Comment: Текст привела дословно. Официальные новости по каналу Вести 24. Никакой иронии там не было. Каждый первый в значении каждый. А в нормативных словарях-справочниках не встречали?

Comment: Вообще ирония по поводу аритмии - это не очень-то порядочно.